# List of a subclass within its class

Tags: java, oop

The context here is a school project for a Library system, the library has both magazines and books.

We have an abstract class `Register` which is extended by `Book` and `Magazine`. Now there's need to implement a `Copy` class , that can be used for both books and magazines, which contains return date, owner, yadda yadda.

Now this has become very confusing for us, `Copy` should extend either `Book` or `Magazine`, and these two must have an ArrayList of their copies inside them.

I'm sorry for the lack of especification in the question but we're absolutely stuck and confused on the matter of implementing a subclass list within its superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, seems that `Copy` class should not extend any of those classes, but instead have an association to `Register`, like this:

```
public class Copy {
    Register original;
    Register copy;
}
```

In this way, you can know the original `Register` instance and the copy of this. The problem with the above design is that you can have an original of type `Book` and a copy of type `Magazine`, or viceversa. To solve this, you can use generics:

```
public class Copy<T extends Register> {
    T original;
    T copy;
}
```

Then, in `Book` class, you may have something like this:

```
public class Book {
    List<Copy<Book>> copies;
}
```

Comment: The Copy class is for physical copies, a Book/Magazine class may have no copies, Book/Magazine contains title, genre, etc, its just an entry register.

Comment: Also, I've never seen the use of "<" in a class, what is it called?

Comment: @Mojimi For first comment, this design supports it. For second comment, it's called generics, as described in the answer: *you can use generics*.

Comment: sorry for bringing this back, I'm just didn't get why did you put two Register, original and copy

Comment: But  I did now understand what you did, although I'm not sure I'm allowed to use generics since we have not been teached that yet. So I was thinking of simply parsing Book or Magazine as parameter on Copy constructor? so I just use generics on the constructor instead, its easier to explain